# Thread exception on changing imageview

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, android-imageview

Whenever I try to pause an activity using a thread for some time and I use a function to change the image view resources inside the thread it gives me an exception saying only the original thread can change it. Now I know that is because the view is declared in the original activity and not in my thread. Is there some other way to pause the activity and do it while the activity is paused and is there any way to change those params in the declared thread. Solution of both will be highly appreciated

Comment: Only UI thread can change UI. Do You need to change the view or it's content? Some code will be helpful.

Comment: i cannot post the code now but i am changing the source of my image view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do the background task, and update you UI view. If AsyncTask is too limiting, I recomend reading Google's own documentation on [threads and Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html). They provide examples of best practice for updating the UI thread.

Based on your explanation, one possible solution could be that your background thread sends a message (Runnable) to the main thread when the imageView should be changed. When the UI thread receives this message, it could for example invalidate some UI elements while the content is changed.

Comment: well i will  be definitely trying your solution but i thought of a easier and a newbie compatible one I am changing the image source an have used a count down timer which exactly stops my activity for required time and then mi am performing what i wanted to do in it OnFinish method.